# Accessing element labels for repeated subrules; e.g. parsing "a IN (1, 2, 3)" with ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr

I'm trying to match syntax like this,

`a in (1, 2, 3)`

So I wrote:

```
| Identifier IN '(' ( inner = (StringLiteral | IntegerLiteral) ','? )+ ')'
{
    /// print what?
}
```

It matches but how can I retrieve all the `$inner.text` and use them in the outer block?

It looks like `'(' ( inner = (StringLiteral | IntegerLiteral) ','? )+ ')'` cannot return a user-defined value like a lexer rule, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this section of the manual: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules#ParserRules-RuleElementLabels

Basically, you need to do `inner += Literal`, that way inner will be defined as a `List<Literal>`, with all the elements added to it.

Note also, that because your comma is optional (`','?`), `a in (1 2 3)` and `a in (1 2, 3,)` are also valid inputs. Something like this:

```
array : '{' el+=INT (',' el+=INT)* '}' ;
```

(from the link above) may be closer to what you want.